# After insert plug&play Bluetooth dongle, ubuntu 18.04 EXT-fs error shows and continues there after, restart or power off causes crash the OS

Tags: bluetooth

1. I have dual-boot win-10 and ubuntu 18.04
2. A bluetooth mouse& key-board works fine as well as wifi.
3. problem when booting only after I plugin bluetooth dongle for headphone.[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZybc.jpg)

Comment: There simply isn't enough information here. What's the output of `lsusb`? What BT adapter is it? Does it say it supports Linux?

Comment: I don't know the BT brand it is 4.0 and lsusb is 'Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)'

Comment: Are you sure you have the same problems without the dongle plugged in?

Comment: No, with out dongle [18.04] there was no problem, but i am running 19.10 now. It seems ok with dongle now, if this happen i will let ask again.